# How to install Hadoop on Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit?

Tags: 12.04, java, hadoop

> I want to install hadoop on my Asus laptop running Ubuntu 12.04.

**When I tried to format the new File system, at that time I got an error**

```
 1. $ hadoop namenode -format or  

 2. $ hdfs namenode -format
```

**it shows..**

```
No command hdfs found
```

I am not getting why it shows error like that, because I executed all previous command successfully.

Answer (score 1):

While searching for solution to your problem, I came across the same problem on stackoverflow- [Hadoop command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369102/hadoop-command-not-found).

Maybe this can help you.

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: Have you referred to My Learning's [Installing Hadoop on Ubuntu 12.04 - single node](http://www.mylearning.in/2012/10/installing-hadoop-on-ubuntu-1204-single.html)?